# Need a local branch for others code fetch in git

Tags: git, github, git-branch, collaboration, git-fetch

My colleague and I are working on a same project, my friend create repository on his remote server like GitHub, then I forked his repository and I have cloned it into machine local machine. The thing i want to do I need to create a local branch "devlp_b" for getting his code, means I want to fetch code from his remote repo to my local branch "devlp_b", after that I work on that branch and merge back to my local master branch.

**Briefly**

Need a local branch `devlp_b` for manually fetch others repo code, ( I don't want that branch into my remote repository, that only reside in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

When you cloned the  repository, you would probably have used a command such as

```sh
git clone <some remote site>
```

In your local copy, you would have a remote called `origin` which  points to `<some remote site>`.

If you cd into this directory, and issue the command

```sh
git remote -vv
```

you will see the details of `<some remote site>` (maybe `ssh://xxx`  or `https://xxx`).

---

In this directory, you could do

```sh
git fetch origin
git checkout -b devlp_b -t origin/<remote branch name>
```

to have a branch `devlp_b` which tracks the `<remote branch name>` you want.

If you are working in another git directory that you created separately, first you need to add the remote:

```sh
git remote add another <some remote site>
git fetch another
git checkout -b devlp_b -t another/<remote branch name>
```

to have a branch `devlp_b` which tracks `<remote branch name>`.

In either case, you can then use the command `git pull --rebase` to update.

Comment: I need to point the **devlp_b** branch some else code from the remote source in my local machine, after done code manipulation i want to merge the code master and push to origin.

Comment: So I think you need to use my last example then.